# what is the Japanese word for "Walk-in Appointment"?

Tags: words

For example: "My doctor's bookings were full today, so I had to go early to try and catch a walk-in appointment."

Comment: Not the answer you were looking for but you could also say "so I had to go early and try to get in without an appointment"

Comment: Also found [this article](https://good-eikaiwa.tokyo/2018/07/04/%E3%80%90%E5%8C%BB%E7%99%82%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%80%91walk-in-or-appointment/) which points out that it's actually not common to need an appointment to see a doctor in Japan, unlike the USA for example. Just found it interesting. It used the phrase "立ち寄り"

Comment: ^ They gave the word 立ち寄り as just a direct translation of "walk-in". We don't use the word to talk about 予約なし診療、受付順 in the hospital.

Comment: As there may be other non-native-English speakers here than me, to clarify, I think Chocolate's message meant that the 予約なし　("without time reservation") or　受付順　(something towards "first-come-first-serve") would both be OK.

Answer (score 4):

"Walk-in appointment" is not regarded as 予約 ("appointment") in Japan. It will usually be treated as 予約なし診療 (literally "appointment-less visit") or 予約外診療 (literally "outside-appointment visit") in Japan. This often means waiting for a long time in a hospital.

Other options are:

- 当日予約: if you managed to make an appointment over the phone several hours before the visit
- 飛び込み診療: this is the same as 予約なし診療 but sounds negative

Answer (score 2):

飛{と}び込{こ}み is an expression with means jump in unannounced.

For example, a "walk-in patient" would be a 飛び込みの患者{かんじゃ}.